# modules in node.js and their behavior

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I'm trying to call an object from a module twice by passing it a value. I expected him to remember my values and continue working with them, but this does not seem to be the case. Tell me how to do it correctly.

**app.js**

```
const {myModule} = require('./myModule')
myModule.setId(Math.random())
myModule.setId(Math.random())
```

**myModule.js**

```
const m1 = {
    id: 0,

    setId: function (id) {
        console.log('setId', id)
        m1.id = id
        setInterval(m1.showId, 1000)
    },

    showId: function () {
        console.log(m1.id)
    }
}

module.exports.myModule = m1
```

**result (console.log):**

```
setId 0.8959027779690547
setId 0.12421047073064084
0.12421047073064084
0.12421047073064084
0.12421047073064084
0.12421047073064084
0.12421047073064084
0.12421047073064084
0.12421047073064084
0.12421047073064084
```

**I expect there will be output to the console:**

```
setId 0.8959027779690547
setId 0.12421047073064084
0.8959027779690547
0.12421047073064084
0.8959027779690547
0.12421047073064084
0.8959027779690547
0.12421047073064084
0.8959027779690547
0.12421047073064084
```

Comment: There is only a single `m1` object and it stores only a single `.id` value. Why would you expect it to remember multiple values?

Comment: There are many possible solutions: create two objects, keep the `id` as a local variable (and make the interval callback local as well, removing `m1.showId()`), etc… without knowing your use case we can't tell what's "correct"

Comment: @Bergi, I would like each call to : `myModule.set Id(Math.random())`
to start working with a new object without interfering with the work of the previous one. Because it is planned to work in the background for a long time.
The **id** variable should be at the top, because there are several functions that can access it.

Comment: You didn't plan to work with a particular value. You planned to access the then-current value of the property. You can't have only a single `id` variable (that is accessed by several functions) as well as keep separate values (for different scheduled background work).

Comment: If you want it to start working with a `new Object`, then why is there _only one `Object`_? That's the crux of the issue here: you didn't really import a "module", you imported a "singleton": an already instantiated instance of an Object. Calling `setId` on it just continuously sets it on _that one object_, the singleton. If you want multiple, you need to turn it into a class, create an object for every Id and then set them on each.